# Any known "gotchas" with Vista & eSATA?

Tags: windows-vista, external-hard-drive, esata

I have a Western Digital eSATA external HDD and have been trying to get it to work with a Medion laptop running Vista Home Premium.  No luck whatsoever.  Is it likely to be a Windows driver issue, or just an incompatibility with the laptop?

Comment: This is definitely the kind of question that belongs over on superuser.com - especially now that it's out of beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eSATA works on Vista for the most part.  The problem comes when you want to remove the device;  the nForce Vista x86 driver (circa 2007) would bluescreen when you removed the drive.  Not sure if this is still the case now.  Microsoft SATA drivers support removal with a registry fix, [KB950186](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950186) and also [KB961078](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961078).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any reason why an eSATA drive wouldn't work with Vista.

You'd need to post some more details about the problem to get a more meaningful answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if the drive is showing up in the drive manager in administrator tools.  It may simply be it's not formatted.

Comment: It doesn't show up in drive manager.  I know it is formatted because I can access it from another PC via USB.  Interestingly I can't reliably access it via USB on the laptop either.

Comment: It might be worth having a look in device manager to check that there are no unknown devices. I'm just wondering if the esata port is on a different controller that hasn't got drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive still fails to show up try this. Connect and disconnect it whilst Device Manager is open. See if there is any activity under hard disks or controllers.